# rails multiple forms in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have `index` method that displaying two forms `Sign in` and `Sign up`, that means user can create an account and a log in from same place.

so I have `users controller` with `index` method that displaying a view with `Sign in` and `Sign up` form with two partials one is `_signin.html.erb` and `_signup.html.erb` in `index.html.erb`.

Any Idea How can I handle `new` and `create` methods from `users` and `sessions` controllers (may be I can ignore new method)?

Comment: Are you still having problems with this? Asking because you unaccepted my answer.

Comment: @amesee - see http://www.reddit.com/ - register page, both sign in and sign up on same page, I am looking something like that

Comment: That's just a matter of showing both forms on the same page. One for signing in and another for signing up, where each form sends requests to `sessions/create` or `users/create` respectively. Both answers on this page pretty much explain how to do that. Are you just not familiar enough with rails to understand this? I mean the problem of user authentication and user creation is pretty much solved in almost every intro to rails book and tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

As long as each form is being rendered with the correct model object and/or the correct value to the `:url` option, each form should send the expected request (assuming you're rendering your forms with `form_for`).

For example, your sign in form should start with something like this::

```
<%= form_for :session, :url => sessions_path %>
  #...
<% end %>
```

As long as a `POST` request (the default from form submissions) is sent to a "collections" resource (i.e. `/sessions`) it will route the request to the `create` action in your `SessionsController` or whatever you named your controller.

For signing up, you probably have something like this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

The `@user` model object will assume the request should go to `/users`. Again this will call your `create` action in your `UsersController`.

Of course, all this is also assuming your `config/routes.rb` file is just declaring each resource with something like:

```
resources :users
resources :sessions, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

You usually have each form in separate views such as

```
match 'sign_in', :to => 'sessions#new'
match 'sign_up', :to => 'users#new'
```

But if you only want to display these forms in an `index.html.erb` view then these routes are no longer necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= form_for :signin,:url=>{:controller=>"yourcontroller",:action=>"signin"},:html=>{:id=>"signin_form"} do |f|%>
  ...
<%end%>

<%= form_for :signup,:url=>{:controller=>"yourcontroller",:action=>"signup"},:html=>{:id=>"signup_form"} do |f|%>
...
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple workaround that I found was that if the two forms have at least one uniquely named parameter, then you can simply route the POST request to a single action. Then within the action check which parameter exists and execute the corresponding code. You end up having essentially two actions within one action in your controller.

```
def create
   if params[:username] and !params[:name]
     # You know that the user pressed submit on whichever form 
     # has a field that fills params[:username].
     # So do the action with that form's parameters here
     # i.e, login an existing user

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html {redirect_to '/home', notice: "Login successful"}
     end

   elsif params[:name] and !params[:username]
     # You know that the user pressed submit on whichever form 
     # has a field that fills params[:username].
     # So do the action with that form's parameters here
     # i.e, create a new user

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html {redirect_to '/onboard', notice: "Thanks for signing up"}
     end
   end
end
```

Just be sure to have it configured in your routes.rb so that when a POST request comes from the page the two forms are on, it will direct to this action in this controller.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this is a very, very bad idea: it is super inflexible as well as error-prone